# При чтении объектов из файла считывается только первый объект

Tags: java

При вводе с клавиатуры палиндромы ( слова которые пишутся одинаково с начала и с конца) сохраняются в файл. После перезапуска программы и очередного ввода файл дополняется новыми объектами , но из файла считывается только первый объект. Как считать данные со всего сохраненного файла?

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filename = "palindromw1.plr";

        // создадим список объектов, которые будем записывать
        Set<Palindrome> palindrome = new HashSet<Palindrome>();


            //palindrome.add(new Palindrome("oko"));
           // palindrome.add(new Palindrome("sasas"));
          //  palindrome.add(new Palindrome("uuuuuuuuu"));
           // palindrome.add(new Palindrome("baaaaaab"));
           // palindrome.add(new Palindrome("tot"));
        String ch;
        do{

            Scanner kbd = new Scanner( System.in );

            palindrome.add(new Palindrome(kbd.nextLine()));

            System.out.println("Хочешь добавить еще палиндром? (y/n):");
            ch = kbd.next();

        }
        while (ch.equals("y"));

        try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename,true)))
        {

            oos.writeObject(palindrome);
            oos.close();
            oos.flush();
            System.out.println("File has been written");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        // десериализация в новый список
        //ArrayList<Palindrome> newPalindrome= new ArrayList<Palindrome>();
        Set<Palindrome> setPalindrome = new HashSet<Palindrome>();

        try
                (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)))
        {
            //ois.readObject(setPalindrome);
            setPalindrome= (Set<Palindrome>) ois.readObject();
            for(int i=0;i< setPalindrome.size() ;i++){
                System.out.println();
            }
            ois.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        for(Palindrome p : setPalindrome)
            System.out.printf("Name: %s \t", p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<Palindrome> palindromes = new HashSet<Palindrome>();
// read data from file if file exists:
...
palindromes = (Set<Palindrome>)ois.readObject();

// add new items
do {
  palindromes.add(...);
} while ...

// save palindromes back to file
...
oos.writeObject(palindromes);
```